# Chown and chmod for a big number of files

Tags: chmod, chown

The server is Apache and a bunch of folders with root privileges ~ 1 200 000 folders in each file to 1. Everything is on *Amazon aws*, *linux ubuntu*. Since the disc itself has 22Gb, the number of files stored in the memory unit was increased. The file system is `ext4`, `inode_ratio = 4096`, which makes it possible to store 22GB ~ 6,000,000 inode.

**The problem: everyone needs 2.4 million files to chown www-data.www-data and chmod 0755**

I'm doing: `sudo chown www-data.www-data -R dir /`
eventually runs about 15 minutes and can be established only to the owner of 600,000 files, and does not go beyond.

Searched in an Internet, I found a `xargs -p` and `find`. I can not assemble them, tell me who knows how to set `chown` only those files who are now under the same root and `chmod 0755` for those files that do not have it. Something like this

```
find -rights -rw-r--r-- dir/ | xargs -p chmod 0755 -R dir/
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: if chown stops working, why are you fiddling with chmod?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
find dir -perm 644 | xargs -I {} chmod 0755 -R {}
```